# Can no longer boot into Ubuntu using Windows boot manager

Tags: boot

Just reinstalled Windows 7 pro and Ubuntu is no longer accessible from the windows boot manager as it was before.How do I re-enable booting into Ubuntu?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Ubuntu to windows boot loader using easybcd software in windows view the below link to see details

https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager